# jQuery getJSON function not working in Blogger HTML/Javascript gadget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger, getjson

Relatively new to HTML and javascript, I was experimenting with some small code snippets.

I intend to add an HTML/JavaScript gadget with the following code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('[server_url]', function(data, status) {
      document.write(status);
    });
  });
</script>
```

However, this does not work. I have tested the server URL, it returns JSON correctly.

On the contrary, I could make the following work:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.post('[post_server_url]', "some data");
  });
</script>
```

What is it about the getJSON method that does not work?

Comment: You should check the console. There will most likely be an error telling you what the problem is. At a guess, the first snippet makes a GET request, the second a POST so there's at least one inconsistency. Also the first will turn the response JSON in to an object, the second won't, so if the response isn't JSON you'll have an issue there. Also, never use `document.write`. It's really bad practice. Create new DOM nodes directly.

Comment: I think the syntax is wrong for `$.getJSON`. Check [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jQuery-getJSON-url-data-success)

Comment: @ParagJadhav the syntax is fine - your link even shows that...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's a reference link, not the syntax checker

Comment: That makes no sense. The OPs syntax is fine. The link to the reference you gave shows that the syntax is correct.

Comment: Documentation says `$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {` whereas OP is using `$.getJSON('[server_url]', function(data, status) {`. Is it the same thing? Now I'm curoius.

Comment: @ParagJadhav the 'data' argument for the function is mandatory and the 'status' & 'xhr' are optional.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The original intention was to call getJSON and use the results in a call to post method. I replaced the post method with document.write to debug the issue. 
If I try the same code in a local html file, it works just fine. But not on blogger

Comment: Ahhh, it could be a CORS issue if you're making the request across domains. Press F12 to check the console for errors as I mentioned above

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think you are right. F12 shows that the getJSON call to server was blocked as it expects it to be a secure call, while it is plain http

Comment: Well if it's moaning about SSL, then you can change the URL to `https://example.com...` assuming you have a valid certificate on the domain